# How to print a QRegExp

Tags: qt, debugging, qregexp

I have a list of QRegExp objects which are created in one part of the application, and used at some other part. They are created like:

```
struct HighlightingRule
{
    QRegExp pattern;
    // somoe more stuff... 
};

QStringList keywordPatterns;
for(int i=0; i<keywords.size(); i++)
{
    QString t = QString("\\b") + keywords.at(i).toUpper() + QString("\\b");
    keywordPatterns.append(t);
}

foreach (const QString &pattern, keywordPatterns)
{
    rule.pattern = QRegExp(pattern);
    highlightingRules.append(rule);
}
```

and used like:

```
foreach (const HighlightingRule &rule, highlightingRules) 
{
    QRegExp expression(rule.pattern);
    // do something with it
}
```

and in the place where I use it I would like to see the "pattern" of the expression I'm trying to use ...

How can I print a QRegExp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
qDebug() << expression.pattern();
```

> Returns the pattern string of the regular expression. The pattern has
>   either regular expression syntax or wildcard syntax, depending on
>   patternSyntax().